# Custom horizontal and vertical scrollbar for Bootstrap table

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-table, slimscroll, scrollable-table

I'm using a [bootstrap-table](http://bootstrap-table.wenzhixin.net.cn/) and have a table with [large](http://issues.wenzhixin.net.cn/bootstrap-table/#options/large-columns.html) columns (horizontal scrollbar is visible). My client has the requirement of a slimmer scrollbar in the table. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26427977/custom-scrollbar-for-bootstrap-table) is a solution for a custom scrollbar for a `bootstrap` table, the problem is that it works for a vertical scrollbar, not for a horizontal one.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/he1u2zo0/)

**html**

```
 <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" cellspacing="0" id="mainTable" data-show-toggle="true" data-show-columns="true" data-pagination="true" data-show-filter="true" data-filter-control="true" >
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th data-field="CustomerName">CustomerN</th>
         <th data-field="ProjectName">ProjectN</th>
         <th data-field="ProjectType">ProjectT</th>
         <th data-field="ProjectDetails">ProjectD</th>
         <th data-field="ProjectLocation">ProjectL</th>
         <th data-field="ProjectTiming">ProjectT</th>
         <th data-field="ProjectTeam">ProjectT</th>
         <th data-field="ProjectStatus">ProjectS</th>
         <th data-field="ProjectProgress">ProjectP</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td>GE Capital Corporation</td>
         <td>Services SOW #1</td>
         <td>Project | T&amp;M</td>
         <td>"Inani fabulas nominavi sea no.\n"+ 
            "Ad quodsi luptatum expetenda eum, sed ludus dicam\n"+ 
            "nominati te, reque causae prompta eos ex. Putent \n"+
            "torquatos mei ei. Te verear offendit per. Vix eu erant\n"+ 
            "doctus delenit, et copiosae indoctum accommodare eum.\n"+ 
            "Errem tritani in qui, te vis legere saperet corpora.\n"+ 
            "Eu mei nobis pertinacia, in has putent virtute voluptua,\n"+ 
            "ne probo dicta utinam nam."
         </td>
         <td>Norwalk, CT</td>
         <td>Feb-Aug 2015</td>
         <td>John, Adam, Pete</td>
         <td>Running</td>
         <td>Empty</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>GE Capital Corporation</td>
         <td>Services SOW #1</td>
         <td>Project | T&amp;M</td>
         <td>"Inani fabulas nominavi sea no.\n"+ 
            "Ad quodsi luptatum expetenda eum, sed ludus dicam\n"+ 
            "nominati te, reque causae prompta eos ex. Putent \n"+
            "torquatos mei ei. Te verear offendit per. Vix eu erant\n"+ 
            "doctus delenit, et copiosae indoctum accommodare eum.\n"+ 
            "Errem tritani in qui, te vis legere saperet corpora.\n"+ 
            "Eu mei nobis pertinacia, in has putent virtute voluptua,\n"+ 
            "ne probo dicta utinam nam."
         </td>
         <td>Norwalk, CT</td>
         <td>Feb-Aug 2015</td>
         <td>John, Adam, Pete</td>
         <td>Running</td>
         <td>Empty</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>GE Capital Corporation</td>
         <td>Services SOW #1</td>
         <td>Project | T&amp;M</td>
         <td>"Inani fabulas nominavi sea no.\n"+ 
            "Ad quodsi luptatum expetenda eum, sed ludus dicam\n"+ 
            "nominati te, reque causae prompta eos ex. Putent \n"+
            "torquatos mei ei. Te verear offendit per. Vix eu erant\n"+ 
            "doctus delenit, et copiosae indoctum accommodare eum.\n"+ 
            "Errem tritani in qui, te vis legere saperet corpora.\n"+ 
            "Eu mei nobis pertinacia, in has putent virtute voluptua,\n"+ 
            "ne probo dicta utinam nam."
         </td>
         <td>Norwalk, CT</td>
         <td>Feb-Aug 2015</td>
         <td>John, Adam, Pete</td>
         <td>Running</td>
         <td>Empty</td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

**javascript**

```
$('#mainTable').bootstrapTable({
});

$('.fixed-table-body').slimScroll({});
```

Comment: It doesn't look like slimScroll supports horizontal scrolling. What browsers do you need to target for this project?

Comment: I didn't notice slimScroll doesn't support horizontal scrollbar, thanks. I need to handle all browsers on Windows (scrollbars in table are too thick).

Comment: You can ry the following plugin [**malihu-custom-scrollbar-plugin**](http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/). Here is a [**fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/DavidDomain/zk4dxcsf/)

Comment: @DavidDomain thanks for response. In your example body of table is horizontal scrollable, but the header of table is fixed.

Comment: Try [perfect scrollbar](https://noraesae.github.io/perfect-scrollbar/). quite an amazing plugin.

Comment: ref link to OP in github issues: https://github.com/wenzhixin/bootstrap-table/issues/1818

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `slimScroll` doesn't support horizontal scrollbars, you could use another `jQuery` plugin (I've used [lionsbars](https://github.com/Charuru/lionbars) for the snippet). But you need to do some tweaks to achieve the purpose of moving the fixed header. Use the plugin that you want but update the header `scrollLeft` property when you scroll on the table body, look at my example:

> On Firefox MacOS the scrollbars can't be customized like in WebKit. Maybe you need to detect system capabilities and apply the plugin only on Windows.

```js
$(function () {
  var $table = $('#table');
  buildTable($table, 50, 50);
});

function buildTable($el, cells, rows) {
  var i, j, row,
      columns = [],
      data = [],
      $header;

  for (i = 0; i < cells; i++) {
    columns.push({
      field: 'field' + i,
      title: 'Cell' + i,
      sortable: true
    });
  }
  for (i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    row = {};
    for (j = 0; j < cells; j++) {
      row['field' + j] = 'Row-' + i + '-' + j;
    }
    data.push(row);
  }
  $el.bootstrapTable('destroy').bootstrapTable({
    columns: columns,
    data: data
  });

  $('.fixed-table-body').lionbars().find(".lb-wrap").on("scroll", function(evt){
    if (!$header) { $header = $('.fixed-table-header'); }
    $header.scrollLeft( this.scrollLeft );
  });
}
```

```css
::-webkit-scrollbar {
   -webkit-appearance: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-table/1.9.1/bootstrap-table.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/Charuru/lionbars@master/js/jquery.lionbars.0.3.js"></script>

<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/Charuru/lionbars@master/css/lionbars.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-table/1.9.1/bootstrap-table.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
  <table id="table" data-height="400" data-show-columns="true"></table>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, detect OS is easy in javascript. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9514179/how-to-find-the-operating-system-version-using-javascript

Comment: You're welcome. Yes, you need something like that to avoid the custom scrollbar on MacOS.